# Where is Simcha?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There is a Jewish statement from R. Nachman which states "mitzva gedola lehiyos b'simcha tamid" It is a great mitzvah to be in Simcha, always.

I know that that's the place where I should worship properly, because it is stated in Tehillim 100:2 "Ivdu et hashem b'simcha, worship God in Simcha" and Dev 28:47 warns us of not being there ("because you did not serve the Lord, your God in Simcha").

Where is Simcha, and how can I get there, so as to ensure that I can be fulfilling this mitzvah properly?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: This question already has an answer about the fella Simcha, but not the town or city that he founded that it sounds like your looking for --it's the first answer here>>http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26174/if-i-am-obligated-to-be-drunk-all-the-time-how-is-purim-different/26197#26197

Comment: Consider marking an answer correct.

Answer (score 4):

Simcha is the area in which the king's words and policies are accepted, as the verse in Esther 8:17 says:

> מְקוֹם אֲשֶׁר דְּבַר-הַמֶּלֶךְ וְדָתוֹ מַגִּיעַ, שִׂמְחָה
>
> The place that the word of the king and his policy reaches is Simcha

You can find a map of Simcha [here](http://www.270towin.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You are already there! As King David says in Tehillim 30:

> הפכת מספדי למחול פתחת שקי ותאזרני שמחה
>
> You have transformed my lament into dancing for me; You loosened my sackcloth and You zoned me in Simcha.

He zoned you, ie, He made you a place to live, in Simcha.

Answer (score 2):

Simha is the name of the larger region around Beit [Oved Edom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obed-Edom). We see this in I Chronicles (15:25):

> לְֽהַעֲל֞וֹת אֶת־אֲר֧וֹן בְּרִית־ה' מִן־בֵּ֥ית עֹבֵֽד־אֱדֹ֖ם בְּשִׂמְחָֽה
>
> To bring up the ark of the covenant fron Beit Oved Edom in Simha.

Answer (score 2):

It's a long and winding road to Simcha.

First, go down Malchut Avenue, and take a right at Torah Parkway. Because of recent construction on this road, stop and ask the guy in the black hat and long beard for *devarim* (directions). He'll ask for your *shemot* (names), and make sure to answer honestly or he'll lead you *bemidbar* (in the wilderness).

If you can pass Torah Parkway, you'll end up on Yesod Road which splits in two. Don't go to the right since it will take you a *netzach* (eternity) to get there. Rather, go to the left onto Hod Road and gaze at the vistas of splendor.

Then, as you continue onto Gevurah Street, make sure to not deviate left or right or you'll face severe consequences. Once you finally reach Binah Boulevard, you will understand why you should not have gone down Tiferet Street despite its beauty a couple steps ago.

Your crowning achievement will be reaching Keter Way which leads directly to Simcha. After realizing the hardship of getting to Simcha and the joy of being there, you will wonder why you hadn't moved there sooner.

Answer (score 1):

This refers to the most famous Breslover chossid.

Originally from Toronto, having learned with some of the great Sages of Jerusalem he eventually decided to give his talents to Rav Nachman and spreading the message of Na Nach

Behold I present to you: ***Simcha*** NaNach

https://youtu.be/D3fK7egeLgk
 Simcha nan nach nachman meuman breslove na nach ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know history or geography well enough to determine where this area is. Be warned that Shlomo HaMelech said that it's futile to go here in [Koheles 2:1](http://sefaria.org/Ecclesiastes.2.1):

> אמרתי אני בלבי לכה נא אנסכה בשמחה וראה בטוב והנה גם הוא הבל
>
> I said in my heart, "Come, I will treat you in Simchah, and will see Good." Behold - that, too, is futile.

David, who said one must serve Hashem in Simchah, and Moshe, who criticized us for not serving Hashem there, were reflecting on their times, when it was possible to go there. I am unsure what R' Nachman was thinking.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain?